# How to clone a shared private git repo on Colab?

Tags: git, github

I'm having trouble cloning a Git private repository that has been shared with me on Github, using Colab. I've tried these:

```
!git clone https://<my_username>:<my_password>@github.com/<shared_private_repo_username>/<private_repo>.git
!git clone https://<my_username>:<my_password>@github.com/<my_username>/<private_repo>.git
```

I get the error:

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for <url_used>
```

I cloned my own repository to check and it works.

How can I access the files in the shared repository?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have [2FA activated](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa): you would have to use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) instead of your password.
If it owrk for your personal repository, this should not be the issue.

Try also an SSH URL

```
git clone git@github.com:<shared_private_repo_username>/<private_repo>.git
```

Assuming you have [configured SSH](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) on your GitHub account.